# Sending Email with Node Mailer and Sendgrid in Angular MEAN stack using angular-fullstack from Yeoman

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, email, express

I am trying to understand where to locate the logic to send an email via a contact form in my Angular App (using angular-fullstack MEAN stack from Yeoman).

I can add the logic to send an email in the app.js file on the server side using nodemailer and sendgrid and everything works and an email is sent every time I refresh the server, however I am a little fuzzy on where to place the logic so that it only gets sent once the form is submitted and it hits the server side.

This is what the create action looks like on the Express JS side...

```html
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  Contact.create(req.body, function(err, contact) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(201, contact);

  });
};
```

Here is the code in app.js that is working, but obviously not in the right place...

```html
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');

var options = {
 auth: {
  api_user: 'username', // 'SENDGRID_USERNAME' - Recommended to store as evn variables
  api_key: 'password', // 'SENDGRID_PASSWORD'
 }
};

var mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

var email = {
 to: 'sendto@email.com',
 from: 'sendfrom@email.com',
 subject: 'Test Email',
 text: 'Awesome Email',
 html: '<b>Bold and Awesome Email</b>'
};

mailer.sendMail(email, function(err, res) {
 if (err) {
  console.log(err)
 }
 console.log(res);
});
```

Coming from a rails background my initial thought is to stick the logic in the create action so that if the object is created successfully the email gets sent. Is this a correct way of thinking about it in this scenario...I am new to the MEAN stack.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a route on the server that you can post form values to from Angular using $http.post.
The following lets you enter details in an Angular form. The form is then posted to Node where the req.body values are extracted and added email object. The email is then send by SendGrid.

*SERVER.JS*

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dotenv = require('dotenv'); 

dotenv.load(); //load environment variables from .env into ENV (process.env).

var sendgrid_username   = process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME;
var sendgrid_password   = process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD;

var sendgrid   = require('sendgrid')(sendgrid_username, sendgrid_password);
var email      = new sendgrid.Email();

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //needed for req.body
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

app.post('/email', function(req, res) {
    email.addTo(req.body.to);
    email.setFrom(req.body.from);
    email.setSubject(req.body.subject);
    email.setText(req.body.text);
    email.addHeader('X-Sent-Using', 'SendGrid-API');
    email.addHeader('X-Transport', 'web');

    sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {
    if (err) { 
        return res.send("Problem Sending Email!!!!");
    }
        console.log(json);
        res.send("Email Sent OK!!!!");
    });
});
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port')  ) ;
});
```

*INDEX.HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- CSS -->
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="emailForm">    
        <div class="group">      
          <input type="email" name="to" ng-model="email.to" ng-required="true">
          <label>To</label>
        </div>
        <div>      
          <input type="email" name="from" ng-model="email.from" ng-required="true">
          <label>From</label>
        </div>
        <div>      
          <input type="text" name="subject" ng-model="email.subject" ng-required="true">
          <label>Subject</label>
        </div>
        <div>      
            <textarea ng-model="email.text" name="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here.."></textarea>
        </div>

        <button id="emailSubmitBn" type="submit" ng-click="submitEmail()">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*CLIENT SIDE APP.JS*

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.submitEmail = function() {

            console.log("TEST");
        //Request
        $http.post('/email', $scope.email) 
        .success(function(data, status) {
            console.log("Sent ok");
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            console.log("Error");
        })
    };
});
```