# Attach file to the Form with Nodemailer and Angular

Tags: angularjs, express, attachment, nodemailer

I followed [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354191/post-angular-form-data-to-node-js-with-sendgrid-nodemailer) guidance to attach a file to the form. But keep getting an Internal error 500 and Error 400. I couldn't find any tutorial with similar task. If you can accompany me, I would be very grateful!

> Server.js

```
var mailOptions = {
   from: data.contactFrom, // sender address
   contactEmail: data.contactEmail,
   to: 'somebody@gmail.com', // list of receivers
   subject: "Request for a Quote from " + data.contactName, // Subject line
   contactMsg: data.contactMsg, // plaintext body
  attachments: [{ filename: req.file.originalname, content: req.file.buffer]};

console.log(mailOptions)

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){ return console.log(error); }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    res.json(info);
});
```

> Client.js

```
app.controller('QuoteCtrl', ['$scope','$http', 
function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.message = {};
   $scope.sendMail = function () {

    // //Include the file in AJAX request
    var formData = new FormData();
       Object.keys($scope.message).forEach(function(key) {
          formData.append(key, $scope.message[key]);
       });

      $http.post('/send/sendQuote', formData, $scope.message, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}}).
        success(function(data) {
         $scope.message = data;
      });

    $scope.message = {};
   }
```

}]);

What are possible errors and any improvements to make life easier?

Comment: I used a different version to send the e-mail. 

I guess you are using the Nodemailer package. I used the sendgrid plugin for Nodemailer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-sendgrid-transport.

That's why my code differs from yours. In case you are using Sendgrid i recommend switching to that version if it's still supported. 

I think your server cannot post the form because of errors which causes the 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what worked form me. I used FormData including input file and req.body values.

> Server.js

```
router.post('/send', upload.array('attachment', 4), 
function(req, res, next) {

    //attaching files
    var attachementList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
        attachementList.push({
            filename: req.files[i].originalname,
            path: req.files[i].path
        });
    }

    var mailOption = {...}


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){...});
```

> Client.js

```
var formData = new FormData();

    //select input file
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
    var files = fileSelect.files;
    for(var i =0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];

        formData.append('attachment', file, file.name);
    }
    formData.append('bday', $scope.application.bday);

    $http.post('/send/sendVoice', formData, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }, $scope.application).
                success(function(data) {
           $scope.application = data;
      });
```