# Angular with Firebase and Node JS?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently using Angular with Firebase for authentication and storing some datas. I want to send email to the user using Angular. I found a way to send emails but using nodejs. Is it possible to still use nodejs for sending emails only and still use my firebase database?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do whatever you like.
However, you would have to create an API or a Webhook with Node.js just to do it.

I would recommend you to use SendGrid or Sendwithus as they already have their API's.

In this thread you can find a way to do it:
[Sending Email with Node Mailer and Sendgrid in Angular MEAN stack using angular-fullstack from Yeoman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326027/sending-email-with-node-mailer-and-sendgrid-in-angular-mean-stack-using-angular) .